# Tensorflow extremely slow after switching to python3

Tags: python, tensorflow, python-3.5

I developed a CNN using tensorflow and python2.7. I am now switching my code to python3.5. I have both python versions on my machine and I have two tensorflow versions installed (one through pip and one through pip3). I am using Linux 16.04.

When I try to run my code using the python3 command, it takes a very long time to load and doesn't start training (where it used to take 3 seconds). It slows down my entire machine, so it's probably a memory issue. My coworker gets a memory error when running the same code on Windows (his machine has 128GB of memory).

My CNN has only two convolutional layers and one fully connected layer, and I'm loading less than 100MB of data.

Why is tensorflow acting differently when I change the python version?

Comment: Maybe your python3 env doesn't have the cpp protobuf's installed? The following should print cpp, `python -c "from google.protobuf.internal import api_implementation; print(api_implementation._default_implementation_type)"`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! The command prints cpp

Comment: could also try this if on linux, in case the two versions were compiled with different allocator libraries  `sudo apt-get install google-perftools;
export LD_PRELOAD="/usr/lib/libtcmalloc.so.4"`

Comment: Thanks! I found a huge 127GB malloc in my code that came up after I installed perftools. I went back to an older version of the py3.5 code and the problem disappeared. Still not sure what could have caused this...